# How can jmpq end up at the wrong place?

Tags: debugging, assembly, x86-64, intel

I am debugging some problems with the relocation of code loaded by llvm's runtime linker. One odd thing that happens is a segfault after calling a function that has been relocated via `R_X86_64_PLT32`. In that case, llvm creates an entry in a GOT (global offset table?) and makes an indirect jump. The `callq` instruction ends up here:

```
0x7ffff7f12021        jmpq   *0xded21(%rip)        # 0x7ffff7ff0d48
```

So I'd expect the next instruction to be at 0x7ffff7ff0d48. Now that location does not look like real code to me, but that's another story. What bothers me is that after a one step, I end up here:

```
0x3415b20       adc    %bl,0x323(%rsi)
```

This is a completely different location, and source of a segfault that even seems to kill gdb. How did jmpq end up here? Is there some truncation going on?

Comment: The address 0x7ffff7ff0d48 where the address being jumped to is stored, not where it will jump to. I have no idea why the value stored there would be incorrect (ie. 0x3415b20).

Comment: Oh my, I just learned that it takes the value of the next instruction and in the process totally forgot about the indirection.